# RXTXcomm library and linux

Tags: linux, rxtx

This not a question but for the record :

- I am using UBUNTU and JAVA OPEN JDK 6.0
- I've experienced SerialEventListener + notifyOnDataAvailable. The fact is that the listener doesn't trigger when data is available on the serial port.

I've solved the problem :

- I've installed JRE1.7 and jdk1.8 form Oracle website
- I've copied librxtxSerial.so from the linux openjdk in the corresponding directory of jdk1.8
  (/jdk1.8.0_11/jre/lib/amd64)

Then it works. I guess the openjdk is not compatible with RXTXcomm.

Good luck